# Android app : show PreferenceFragment as a dialog?

Tags: android, fragment, android-preferences, android-dialogfragment

I'm new to Android (with iOS background) and I would like to do the following : 
I've made a PreferenceFragment in which I ask the user his credentials to connect to my WebServices. When I detect that those credentials are rejected by my server, I would like to show to my user a dialog (modal) where he can edit his preferences (credentials).

I've manage to do it using PreferenceActivity. So when I click a bouton, I execute the following code :

```
Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), PreferencesConnection.class);
startActivity(settingsActivity);
```

Which load a PreferenceActivity as a Dialog with an XML ressource :

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_connection);
```

But this is depreciated. I can I do the same, but with Fragment? Should I use DialogFragment to show my PreferenceFragment, or not? Would it be easier to just rebuilt my credentials in a DialogFragment? Should I use a Activity instead of Fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do an old fashioned, single page settings screen without PreferenceHeaders, do as follows:

In your activity that invokes the settings screen (example is in onMenuItemSelected):

```
case R.id.menuSettings:
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(settingsIntent, GC.SETTINGS_ACTIVITY_ID);
        break;
```

In your XML folder, create an old fashioned PreferenceScreen. PreferenceCategory, ListPreference, CheckBoxPreference, etc. Do not use PreferenceHeaders

Create a settings activity:

```
package com.mycompany.project1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private final static String TAG = "SettingsAcitivity";

    public SettingsActivity() {}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyLog.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new LocationFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class LocationFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        private String TAG = "LocationFragment";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            MyLog.d(TAG, "onCreate");
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        }
    }
}
```

Do not associate a dialog theme with the settings activity. You will get weird results for certain preference types such as radio buttons. (I tried the dialog thing and couldn't find the coding error(s). Everything worked fine when I used the standard activity theme instead of the dialog theme. Evidently the holo dialog theme collides with settings definitions.

Note: I used startActivityforResult so I could reinitialize specific settings values that changed.

Comment: Look like it works great! But I'm a little concern about compatibility. Will it works on future device when using PreferenceFragment and PreferenceActivity? And what about older devices?

Comment: I will accept your answer, because it does respond really well to the question! But I just found out that a lot of people are still on Android 2.3. So this solution wont works for them. Do you have a idea how to make it works?

Comment: I'm no help for 2.x compatibility. As of January, 40% of the market is at sdk 15 or greater (ICS or better) and growing at more than a 10% rate per quarter. I decided that my new apps will be set to a min and target sdk of 15. Simply stated, I decided I don't want to use the compatibility library, add extra drawable folders, add extra layout libraries, write my own download manager, or switch between activities and fragments. It's bad enough writing for multiple screens without adding release dependent code. My apps that are at 2.x don't have a max sdk set and run fine up to Jelly Bean.